# Multiple left joins in LINQ query C#

Tags: c#, linq, left-join

I need help with a LINQ query that has multiple left joins.  This is LINQ to EF4.  I wrote the SQL and converted it to LINQ not knowing that the 'join' in LINQ is an inner join.  I've looked all over for an example but can only find examples with one left join.  Any help is much appreciated!

Here's the SQL:

```
SELECT
    s.FirstName, s.LastName, s.StakeholderID, op.ParticipantID, op.SchoolID, oc.CycleNumber, 
    st.SessionTypeID, st.SessionDescription, CONVERT(varchar(10),os.SessionDt,101) AS SessionDTrr, 
    os.OSStatus, oee.EvaluatorID
FROM
    Stakeholders s LEFT JOIN ObservationParticipants op ON s.StakeholderID = op.StakeholderID
    LEFT JOIN ObservationEvaluateeEvaluators oee ON op.ParticipantID = oee.EvaluateID
    LEFT JOIN ObservationCycles oc ON oee.ObservationEvaluateeEvaluatorID = oc.ObservationEvaluateeEvaluatorID
    LEFT JOIN ObservationSessions os ON oc.ObservationCycleID = os.ObservationCycleID
    LEFT JOIN SessionTypes st ON os.SessionTypeID = st.SessionTypeID
WHERE 
    oee.EvaluatorID = evaluatorID
```

Here's the LINQ that I converted the above statement too.  I need the joins to be left joins though.  Can anyone assist with converting the joins in this LINQ to left joins?

```
from s in Stakeholders
join op in ObservationParticipants
on s.StakeholderID equals op.StakeholderID
join oee in ObservationEvaluateeEvaluators
on op.ParticipantID equals oee.EvaluateID
join oc in ObservationCycles
on oee.ObservationEvaluateeEvaluatorID equals oc.ObservationEvaluateeEvaluatorID
join os in ObservationSessions
on oc.ObservationCycleID equals os.ObservationCycleID
join st in SessionTypes
on os.SessionTypeID equals st.SessionTypeID
where oee.EvaluatorID == evaluatorID
select new { 
            s.FirstName, s.LastName, s.StakeholderID, 
            op.ParticipantID, op.SchoolID, oc.CycleNumber,
            st.SessionTypeID, st.SessionDescription, os.SessionDt,
            os.OSStatus
            }
```

Comment: http://codingsense.wordpress.com/2009/03/08/left-join-right-join-using-linq/    - i hope, You can help

Comment: Also checkout downloading LinqPad if you set it up correctly it can generate the linq query based on the one you have currently.

Comment: I actually used LinqPad to create the LINQ query above.  I don't think LinqPad can take SQL and turn it into linq though.

Comment: yes it can.. I've done it before I believe I connected it to one of the Entity connections

Answer (score 0):

looks like your are mixing technologies. linq queries objects where as sql queries a relational database. very different things. there are different implementations of linq:
linq to sql
EF query language
linq to xml
linq to NH
linq to kitchen sink

each linq provider will translate the query differently and it's not always apparent how or where the translations will take place.

in this instance you need to inform us of what linq provider you are using, from there we can help translate the sql query to a linq2? statement.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by linq provider.  This is in a project using the Entity Framework.  It's a C# project and I'm using linq to entities.  The SQL statement was provided to me and I only used it as a base to convert to linq.  I have followed this approach before with success.

Comment: a linq provider is an implementation of IQueryable. the basis of linq.